Why does this web scraper using Selenium not return the entire website?
I tried to program a web scraper with Selenium for educational purposes that displays stock market data from ‘The Wall Street Journal’. I want to know the number of advancing and declining issues from this link: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/us
My webscraper looks like this:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

url = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/us"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]")
    data = element.text
    print(f"Found data: {data}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

driver.quit()

For example, if I try to look for the number of advancing issues on the NYSE like this:
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, “/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]”)
I get the following error message:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.205); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

Therefore, I tried to look for the entire body to see if I have access to the data:
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body")

However, I only received the full text from the header, the "Stock Indexes" section and the "Stocks News" section. I did not get any content from the "Markets Diary" section or other parts further down the page.
Increasing the waiting time time.sleep(10) did not change anything.
Why am I not being shown the entire body?

It is possible (actually probable) that most of the data you want is being generated by Javascript in the web page. You should print the data that you first receive to see what is actually returned from the call to driver.get().

Yes, I know most of the data is generated by Javascript. But I can print some parts of the website (for example some stock prices) which are also Javascript generated.

Selenium no longer requires user code to manage the browser driver (as you'll see in the code below).
You also need to bear in mind that WebElement.text does not always reveal what you might expect. This code includes a useful utility function that handles that situation.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
OPTIONS.add_argument("--headless=true")

URL = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/us"

def etext(e: WebElement) -> str:
    if t := e.text:
        return t.strip()
    p = e.get_property("textContent")
    return p.strip() if isinstance(p, str) else ""

with webdriver.Chrome(OPTIONS) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    ec = EC.presence_of_element_located
    selector = By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td[2]"
    if td := wait.until(ec(selector)):
        print("Advancing", etext(td))
    selector = By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[2]"
    if td := wait.until(ec(selector)):
        print("Declining", etext(td))

Output:
Advancing 509
Declining 2,284


Thanks, your function works perfectly. Could you maybe explain why WebElement.text does not work here?

@Lukinator The element may be hidden

I know you've already accepted an answer but it's way more complicated than it needs to be. The code below works just fine.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/us")

advancing = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[aria-label='Issues Advancing'] ~ td")
for cell in advancing:
    print(cell.text)

print("")

declining = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[aria-label='Issues Declining'] ~ td")
for cell in declining:
    print(cell.text)

and it outputs
509
1,157

2,284
3,228


Some explanation...
These CSS selectors find the sibling TDs of the label, either Advancing or Declining, then prints them. The first value is the NYSE, the second is the NASDAQ.

My assumption is that the reason you are having issues with getting the values is because you are using headless mode and the page is dynamic... it needs a few seconds to completely load all the data in the table.

Perhaps the next two XPaths will better address the issues the OP is facing: //td[@aria-label='Issues Advancing']/following-sibling::td[1] and //td[@aria-label='Issues Declining']/following-sibling::td[1]

@SIM Those two XPaths only return the NYSE. You're missing the NASDAQ.

I mistakenly ignored this NASDAQ altogether.
